# Black space displayed in screen during gradle version upgrade

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

If Gradle version 7.0.4 greater then displayed the black spaces in screen.

I faced this issue during SDK and gradle version upgrade in Android Java project
and I found the solution.

**Solution** : Remove targetSdkVersion from Manifest and add it into app/build.gradle at defaultConfig
Like :
Remove to **Manifest.xml**
`<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="33" />`

Add into **build.gradle**
`defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 33 }`